# Как выбрать подход к програмированию, процедурный или объектно ориенированный?

Tags: c++, архитектура, проектирование

При продумывание архитектуры программы нужно определить, как организовать код, и сразу встает проблема которую нужно решить - это подход к программированию, а то есть нужно ли использовать классы (ООП), достаточно ли процедурного подхода к программированию или даже того и другого вместе?

Подскажите как разобраться с этим нюансом.

Comment: Лично для меня вопрос не понятен. Он слишком абстрактный.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, к примеру можно привести сравнивая программирование с рисованием, сначала художник рисует набросок, а потом уже его обрисовывает его красками, так и с программированием сначала надо продумать "каркас" программы, а затем что накодить поверх него, ведь нужно же с чего то начинать программу, что бы потом много раз не начинать заново в случае с не удачной архитектурой. как то так

Comment: Какой смысл в функциональном подходе на фон Неймановской архитектуре?

Comment: @typemoon разъясните что такое фон Неймановскоя архитектура

Comment: Архитектура, на которой все твое ФП превращается в императивный машинный код под капотом. Какой смысл в получении императивного кода путем функциональных извращений?

Comment: @typemoon например на линуксе до сих пор на чистом СИ пишут программы

Comment: Это не функциональный подход, а процедурный.

Comment: @typemoon но ведь функция и процедура это почти одно и то же

Comment: http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/471/327/info

Comment: Функция и процедура — одно и то же. А вот функциональный подход и процедурный — нет.

Comment: Функция это подмножество декартова произведения области определения функции на область ее значений. Императивные комбайны, которые принимают кучу параметров, часть из них изменяют, еще что-то возвращают, или - еще удивительнее! - не возвращают ничего, функциями не являются.

Comment: @Vlad , да спасибо разобрался с этими вещами, так что вопрос отрытый .. функциональный или процедурный?

Comment: Функциональный подход — это о том, что состояние неизменяемо, функции не изменяют глобальное состояние, и и оперируют другими функциями. Процедурный подход — полная противоположность.

Comment: @perfect: А почему нужно обязательно выбирать? Если для какой-то части проекта лучше подходит один из подходов, а для другой — другой, пользуйтесь для каждой своей архитектурой. Нету никакой абсолютной рекомендации.

Comment: @VladD функция и процедура далеко не одно и то же

Comment: @айтишник процедура это функция которая ни чего не возвращает

Comment: @perfect это условность, доставшаяся от, ЕМНИП, паскаля. В C и C++ нет процедур в терминологии. Но есть функция с типом возвращаемого значения void. А по сути твоего вопроса: он крайне дискуссионный и не имеет однозначного ответа. Попробуй его задать на RSDN (http://rsdn.ru).

Comment: @perfect есть общепринятый термин "функциональное программирование" - раздел дискретной математики и парадигма программирования, в которой процесс вычисления трактуется как вычисление значений функций в *математическом понимании* последних (в отличие от *функций как подпрограмм* в процедурном программировании). [википедия на эту тему](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)